# Count rows in pandas Dataframe column wise?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm quite new to Python. 
I've the below sample dataframe `df`.

```
    Col1 Col2 Col3
0   0    1    1
1   1    1    0
2   0    1    1
3   1    0    1
4   0    0    1
```

If I use this code `df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, axis=0)`
And I'm getting result as:

```
    Col1 Col2 Col3
0   3    2    1
1   2    3    4
```

But, I want the result as below (like pivot):

```
    Col_Name   0    1
0   Col1       3    2
1   Col2       2    3
2   Col3       1    4
```

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your solution transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and for new column from index [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, axis=0)

df1 = df1.T.rename_axis('Col_Name').reset_index()
print (df1)
  Col_Name  0  1
0     Col1  3  2
1     Col2  2  3
2     Col3  1  4
```

Another solutions:

First reshape columns by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) or [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and last reshape back by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().unstack()
print (df)
      0  1
Col1  3  2
Col2  2  3
Col3  1  4
```

For new column:

```
df = (df.stack()
        .groupby(level=1)
        .value_counts()
        .unstack()
        .rename_axis('Col_Name')
        .reset_index())
print (df)
  Col_Name  0  1
0     Col1  3  2
1     Col2  2  3
2     Col3  1  4
```

Another solution:

```
df = (df.melt(var_name='Col_Name')
        .groupby('Col_Name')['value']
        .value_counts()
        .unstack()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reset_index()
        )
print (df)
  Col_Name  0  1
0     Col1  3  2
1     Col2  2  3
2     Col3  1  4
```